# " Use of unassigned local variable" error for three local variables but not for the fourth local variable. Why?

Tags: c#

For the following code in C#, why are the errors obtained: -

> Error 1: Use of unassigned local variable `circleArea` 
>   Error 2: Use of unassigned local variable `circleRadius` 
>   Error 3: Use of unassigned local variable `circleDiameter`

but not for `paramaterChoice`; even though it also is an uninitialized local variable?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char paramaterChoice;
    double circleRadius, circleDiameter, circleArea;
    const double PI=3.14;

    Console.WriteLine("If you know the radius press r or R, If you know the diameter press d or D");
    paramaterChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (paramaterChoice)
    {
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Radius of the Circle");
            circleRadius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            circleArea = PI * circleRadius * circleRadius;
            //Console.WriteLine("Area of Cirle is: {0:f2}", circleArea);
            break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Diameter of the Circle");
            circleDiameter = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            circleArea = PI * circleDiameter * circleDiameter / 4;
            //Console.WriteLine("Area of Cirle is: {0:f2}", circleArea);
            break;
    }

    // The error occurs on the next line:
    Console.WriteLine("Parameter: {0}, Radius: {1:f2}, Diameter: {2:f2}, Area: {3:f2}",
        paramaterChoice, circleRadius, circleDiameter, circleArea);

    Console.WriteLine("\nProgram Info: Calculates the Area of a circle");        
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that `paramaterChoice` is unassigned? What does `paramaterChoice = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());` do then?

Comment: What if someone enters a choice other than `r`, `R`, `d`, or `D`? The compiler is trying to help you by detecting situations where your variable won't be assigned.

Comment: Add `default:` to the `switch..case` (what the routine should do on incorrect `paramaterChoice`), e.g. `default: return;`

Comment: How did you get on with the answers below, Hitesh?

Comment: Note that ignoring answers (and indeed ignoring people who remind you) is not going to endear you to the community over the long term. People help each other here on the basis they will get some response, and if everyone abandoned their questions, Stack Overflow would eventually collapse.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
Console.WriteLine("Radius: {0:f2}, Diameter: {1:f2}, Area: {2:f2}", circleRadius, circleDiameter, circleArea);
```

Those values are only assigned in your switch statement, and only if they enter one of your optional values. (either `r`, `R`, `d` or `D`).

Which means if neither one of those was entered, well...

So to fix this, either set the values to 0 to start with:

```
double circleRadius = 0, circleDiameter = 0, circleArea = 0;
```

Or handle the values in your switch statement using

```
default:
//Set values here.
break;
```

`default` basically means `if neither of these was entered`.

Comment: The second solution won't work because in OPs code only one of `circleRadius ` and `circleDiameter` is assigned on "correct" input

Comment: @UnholySheep - Why do you say it wouldn't work? If values are given an assignment in the `default` case, then in all cases they will be assigned before they are used.

Comment: So what value would `circleDiameter` have in `case 'R':`?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the reason you're getting the error is that not all your values are getting assigned before you use them. So you need to either initialize them when you declare them, or ensure that both values are assigned in each case statement (and include a default statement that assigns them).

There is an additional problem if the user does not enter a valid `double` for the radius/diameter input. What I like to do for collecting strongly typed information from the user is to write methods that take in a prompt string and return the strong type that you expect. Then, in that method, keep looping until the user enters a valid value.

For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a strongly typed (double) value from the Console
/// </summary>
/// <param name="prompt">The initial message to display to the user</param>
/// <returns>User input converted to a double</returns>
private static double GetDoubleFromUser(string prompt)
{
    double value;

    // Write the prompt text and get input from user
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    // If input can't be converted to a double, keep trying
    while (!double.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
        Console.Write($"'{input}' is not a valid number. Please try again: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Input was successfully converted!
    return value;
}
```

Then, you can use this in your code as in the example below. Notice that I also made a couple of other changes:

1. Get the user input using `ReadKey`. This reads in the key they pressed, and you don't have to worry about comparing upper or lower case.
2. Set the value for the item that the user didn't enter (either radius or diameter) in the `switch` cases.
3. Use the built-in `Math` properties/methods to get PI and to "square" the radius.
4. Set a `bool` variable called `exit` to true if the user doesn't enter a `R` or a `D`, and then check the value of this before displaying any output (that way we don't display output that they didn't enter, and allow the user to quit in an easy way).

For example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    double circleRadius = 0, circleDiameter = 0, circleArea = 0;
    bool exit = false;

    Console.Write("Press 'R' for radius, 'D' for diameter, or any other key to exit: ");
    ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();

    switch (input.Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.R:
            circleRadius = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
            circleDiameter = circleRadius * 2;
            break;
        case ConsoleKey.D:
            circleDiameter = GetDoubleFromUser("Enter the diameter of the circle: ");
            circleRadius = circleDiameter / 2;
            break;
        default:
            exit = true;
            break;
    }

    if (exit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program exiting.");
    }
    else
    {
        circleArea = Math.PI * Math.Pow(circleRadius, 2);

        Console.WriteLine("Input: {0}, Radius: {1:f2}, Diameter: {2:f2}, Area: {3:f2}",
            input.KeyChar, circleRadius, circleDiameter, circleArea);

        Console.WriteLine("\nProgram Info: Calculates the Area of a circle");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```